# How to get total number of likes on my page through facebook api

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to display the number of users who liked my fb page. How can I get this number from facebook. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: @Bunyip 
I checked insight doc, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/ docs and searched stackoverflow, but i din't find it anywhere

So please help or atleast remove the downvote so others can help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the answer:

url: https://graph.facebook.com/your-app-name

Result will be an array like this:

https://graph.facebook.com/facebook

```
{
"about": "Facebook's mission is to give people the power to share and make the world more open and connected.",
"category": "Product/service",
"company_overview": "Newsroom: http://newsroom.fb.com\nInvestor Relations: http://investor.fb.com/",
"founded": "February 4, 2004",
"is_published": true,
"talking_about_count": 246554,
"username": "facebook",
"website": "http://www.facebook.com/facebook",
"were_here_count": 0,
"id": "20531316728",
"name": "Facebook",
"link": "http://www.facebook.com/facebook",
"likes": 96358786,
"cover": {
   "cover_id": "10151496277356729",
   "source": "http://sphotos-a.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-as2/s720x720/247388_10151496277356729_2043388331_n.jpg",
   "offset_y": 0,
  "offset_x": 0
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

See below answers. I'm sure you will get the idea for doing this.

[How do you get the total likes for a URL (Likes and Shares)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9746887/how-do-you-get-the-total-likes-for-a-url-likes-and-shares)

[How to get total number of Facebook-likes on a photo?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14257042/how-to-get-total-number-of-facebook-likes-on-a-photo)

[How to get share counts using graph API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5699270/how-to-get-share-counts-using-graph-api)

Comment: Thanks Bunyip, all of them were of use but it is more simpler than all. https://graph.facebook.com/<your-app-name>. I will post it as an answer